# Solving Area of shapes

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

I keep getting the same answer to this question:

[image]

I've attached my working out as well.[image]

Comment: One obvious mistake is that the line parallel to the bottom doesn't really cut an interval of length 63m on the right side. This is already enough to screw things up but I haven't looked at your sketch attentively enough to determine if there are more problems with it.

Comment: The problem with your method is that the top and bottom sides are not necessarily parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It is easier to calculate the area with coordinates. The coordinates of the four vertexes are

$$A(0,0),\>\>\>\>B(72,0),\>\>\>C(72+81\cos60,81\sin60),\>\>\>D(-63\cos80, 63\sin80)$$

Use the coordinate area formula for the triangle ABC to calculate its area,

$$S_{ABC} = \frac12| A_x(B_y-C_y) + B_x(C_y-A_y) + C_x(A_y-B_y)|=2525.3$$

Similarly, the area of the triangle ACD is

$$S_{ACD} = \frac12| A_x(C_y-D_y) + C_x(D_y-A_y) + D_x(A_y-C_y)|=3873.6$$

Thus, the total area is

$$S_{ABCD} = S_{ABC} + S_{ACD} = 2525.3+ 3873.6=6398.9$$